# Unable to install package image_transport while installing ardrone_autonomy

Tags: ros, rosmake, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While running rosmake command inside ardrone_autonomy repository I am getting this error:

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package ardrone_autonomy
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rospack deps-manifests ardrone_autonomy
[rospack] Error: package 'ardrone_autonomy' depends on non-existent package 'image_transport' and rosdep claims that 
it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):


Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'ardrone_autonomy'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:207 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264244/unable-to-install-package-image_transport-while-installing-ardrone_autonomy/) by [avirajkhare00](https://answers.ros.org/users/30833/avirajkhare00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is most likely due to you using `rosmake`, as per the [`ardrone_autonomy` documentation](http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), you should install it using `catkin_make`:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy.git -b indigo-devel
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i
$ catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0